# Automatic construction of supercell VESTA

Tags: vesta, supercell

Good afternoon, everyone.Please help me understand my question. When I upload some of my cif structure files, VESTA automatically creates huge supercells. I want to remove this function by standard when I start the program. Maybe someone knows how to do it, like customize some config file?

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Vesta 3.5.8 64-bit

For some cif files I have structures with one unit cell open, for others a huge supercell (attached screenshot). I have not found any regularities between the structures.

When converting a cif file to an xyz file via openbabel, the file opens unit cell (without cell)

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Comment: +1 Please let us know what version of VESTAT you are using, the operating system, and whether this behavior was from a fresh install. Moreover, have you tried with different cif files and had the same thing, have you tried with other formats such as .vasp , POSCAR, or XYZ files? If you could provide screenshot of the supercell and the options found under 'Boundary'.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Added additional information

Comment: @Agrail616, I think there is nothing wrong with what you are getting, this is still a unit cell not a supercell (the solid line box in the middle), I might not sure what is your structure but it looks like a COF or MOF and that's what they look like when you visualize them.. to be sure open your cif file with a text editor and check the unit cell dimension to confirm. If you would like, you can share the cif file in here and I will check.